# Issues after applying Sql 2008 sp4, 'sqlagent100_msdb_upgrade.sql'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

The build version was 2008Std.2531 went to apply SP4 and the upgrade would not complete preventing the engine to come on line.  After some assistance and using the -t902 the engine is up but the SP is not fully applied due to needing to complete the scripts.

```
Log Snippet:  
2015-10-04 13:56:15.79 spid9s      Creating procedure sp_stop_job...
2015-10-04 13:56:15.80 spid9s       
2015-10-04 13:56:15.80 spid9s      Creating procedure sp_cycle_agent_errorlog...
2015-10-04 13:56:15.80 spid9s       
2015-10-04 13:56:15.80 spid9s      Creating procedure sp_get_chunked_jobstep_params...
2015-10-04 13:56:15.81 spid9s      Error: 8116, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2015-10-04 13:56:15.81 spid9s      Argument data type nvarchar(max) is invalid for argument 1 of textptr function.
2015-10-04 13:56:15.82 spid9s      Error: 7125, Severity: 16, State: 4.
2015-10-04 13:56:15.82 spid9s      The text, ntext, or image pointer value conflicts with the column name specified.
2015-10-04 13:56:15.82 spid9s      Error: 7125, Severity: 16, State: 4.
2015-10-04 13:56:15.82 spid9s      The text, ntext, or image pointer value conflicts with the column name specified.
2015-10-04 13:56:15.84 spid9s      Error: 912, Severity: 21, State: 2.
2015-10-04 13:56:15.84 spid9s      Script level upgrade for database 'master' failed because upgrade step 'sqlagent100_msdb_upgrade.sql' encountered error 200, state 7, severity 25. This is a serious error condition which might interfere with regular operation and the database will be taken offline. If the error happened during upgrade of the 'master' database, it will prevent the entire SQL Server instance from starting. Examine the previous errorlog entries for errors, take the appropriate corrective actions and re-start the database so that the script upgrade steps run to completion.
2015-10-04 13:56:15.88 spid9s      Error: 3417, Severity: 21, State: 3.
2015-10-04 13:56:15.88 spid9s      Cannot recover the master database. SQL Server is unable to run. Restore master from a full backup, repair it, or rebuild it. For more information about how to rebuild the master database, see SQL Server Books Online.
2015-10-04 13:56:15.89 spid9s      SQL Trace was stopped due to server shutdown. Trace ID = '1'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
2015-10-04 13:56:16.38 Logon       Error: 17188, Severity: 16, State: 1.
```

I feel there is an issue in MSDB.

> More info added as requested.

When applying the SP4 there was no error indicating a issue.

The SQL engine would not come back online.  The only a solution to allow the engine to come online was adding the -t902 to the startup.  I understand this to prevent the scripts from running.

I placed master and msdb files back prior to the SP4 upgrade, removed the trace flag, once the engine started back it immediately started the upgrade process again with an error at the same point.  I added -t902 back and the engine is up but at this point the SP4 appears to have partially completed.

DBCC on master reports no errors.

How can I determine where the error is in master db that is preventing the SP scripts to complete?

Comment: I feel there is an issue in `master` - "Restore master from a full backup, repair it, or rebuild it"

Answer (score 0):

There are a series of errors in the **master** database here:

> Error: 8116, Severity: 16, State: 1. Argument data type nvarchar(max)
> is invalid for argument 1 of textptr function.
>
> Error: 7125, Severity: 16, State: 4. The text, ntext, or image pointer
> value conflicts with the column name specified.
>
> Error: 7125, Severity: 16, State: 4. The text, ntext, or image pointer
> value conflicts with the column name specified.

These are Severity 16 errors which are correctable errors.  You might need to fix these first to avoid a later problem.

> Error: 912, Severity: 21, State: 2.Script level upgrade for database 'master' failed because upgrade step
> 'sqlagent100_msdb_upgrade.sql' encountered error 200, state 7,
> severity 25.
>
> A Severity 25 error is definitely bad:
>
> This is a serious error condition which might interfere
> with regular operation and the database will be taken offline. If the
> error happened during upgrade of the 'master' database, it will
> prevent the entire SQL Server instance from starting. Examine the
> previous errorlog entries for errors, take the appropriate corrective
> actions and re-start the database so that the script upgrade steps run
> to completion.

What has happened is that you have lost the **master** database:

> Cannot recover the master database. SQL Server is unable to run.
> Restore **master** from a full backup, repair it, or rebuild it. For more
> information about how to rebuild the **master** database, see SQL Server
> Books Online.

As you can see, you are being given 3 possible fixes, the best if which is:

**Restore *master* from a good Full backup.**

You can, of course, try to repair or rebuild the master database, but these can cause you more secondary work to get everything back in order.

**UPDATE WITH EXAMPLE:** Looking for concrete examples, I did find this post by Glenn Berry.

https://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2009/10/04/stupid-dba-tricks/

He outlined that his problem was caused by "cleaning out the SQL Server Install directory, specifically "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Install”. "

This is what lead to his problem with the new install.  What he did to get back on track was:

> I remembered about my clever move of deleting the files in the
> installation directory. I had a test server that had SQL Server 2008
> SP1 CU4 installed, so I zipped up those install files, and e-mailed
> them to myself. Then I logged on to Outlook Web Access from the
> client’s DB server, and pulled down that zip file and copied the
> missing files to the install directory.
>
> Finally, I restarted the SQL Server service, and he was able to
> complete the script level upgrade process of the Cumulative Update,
> and everything was fine.

Perhaps if your old install was deleted prior to the new install, this may give you a window into resolving the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, a copy of the master and msdb flat files prior to service pack was restored while the engine was stopped.  Once the engine was started it tried to continue the update.  How can I determine where the error is in master?

Comment: @Modye - The only concrete example that I could find added inline above

Comment: @ RLF, thanks for the reference, never had a space issue, the files are present.